# Should this table be split in two?

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, performance

I have a table which has 11 columns, now most of the time three columns on this table will be empty, but then if I split in two, there are more queries per table. Whats your suggestions

Comment: @user658911: Do you experience some issues now, with current structure?

Comment: No, but to improve the scalability and reliability

Comment: @user658911: if it works - don't change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of other variables to take into account.  Some that come to mind are:

- How large is the table?
- How big are the three columns that are usually empty?
- What types of queries use the table?
- What type of data is in the columns?  For example, if it is something that belongs in a lookup table, then it may make sense to avoid duplicating data. This one isn't necessarily germane to the question but is worth considering.
- Are the fields indexed (or used in any indexes)?  If so, it would probably increase the cost of INSERTS and DELETES (not so much if they are empty and left unchanged during UPDATE operations).

In general, though, I would say that leaving it as a single table is okay.  11 columns are not that many.  So unless the table is really large (a relative term) and space is at a premium, the simplicity of a single table is a good idea particularly if the data logically belongs in the table.

Comment: The table is contains about 50,000 records with 100 updates per second. The two of the three columns are int and one is float. THe three columns contain views, clicks, ctr.

Comment: Based on this information, my opinion is that it would make sense to leave the table as is.  The data seems to be related, and (assuming float is 4 bytes) then the savings of 12 bytes is minimal and would likely have little impact on updates.  It might add a bit of cost for INSERTS but probably not worth the trouble of moving the data to another table.  However, if those fields are indexed, it could make a difference.  I will add a bit more info about that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary concern is speed, then keeping the table together would grant you less expensive SELECT queries since you won't meed to JOIN.

Comment: Well, I would say it **depends** on **a lot** of facts. Less table is more likely to fit in memory, thus will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think with 11 columns, your performance gains will be minimal either way.  I think it's more personal preference at this point.